# 405 response code when trying to callout to Google

Tags: rest, callout, http

Here is my code for callout.

```
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        req.setEndpoint('https://google.com?q=');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0'); 
        req.setTimeOut(1200);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(account.name);

        res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(res.toString());
```

This is working for other test urls like posttestserver.com but for Google.com, getting response as "Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405". Added `http://google.com` in remote site settings.

Thanks.

Comment: what google service are you trying to post to? Simply posting to google is not allowed

Comment: Hi Eric. I am trying to do a search with account.name in google and return the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't post data directly to google so you need to get data using API.

```
        Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

    req.setEndpoint('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=' + Account.Name);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0'); 
    req.setTimeOut(1200);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    res = http.send(req);
    system.debug(res.getbody());
```

It will return data in Json format as shown below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. Worked perfectly and Thanks for your explanation

Comment: your welcome :)

Comment: btw. which tool did you use above to check the response.

Comment: you can use advance rest client (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), postman etc.